# Create an iso file of EC2 backup on s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, imaging

I just create an AMI instance of EC2 and than upload it S3 using following command:

1.`ec2-bundle-vol -d /mnt -k /root/PrivateKey.pem  --cert /root/Certificate.pem  -u 012345678901`

2.`ec2-upload-bundle -b yourbucketname00404042009 -m /mnt/image.manifest.xml -a your_s3_access_key -s your_s3_secret_access_key`

It uploaded to s3. How to create iso file of the uploaded files?

Comment: Do you mean an ami?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use ec2-register to register the bundle as an AMI.

```
ec2-register --manual
```

will give you an exaustive list of options.